# Get image in CCAnimation Cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-x

n init method am starting one CCAnimation. its fine. at touch ended method am stoping the animation. at the time of stop i need to get the current image of animate.

```
Player = CCSprite::create("AngleSelector1.png");
    Player->setPosition( ccp(size.width / 2, size.height/2) );
    this->addChild(Player);

    //Animation
    CCAnimation *animate = CCAnimation::create();
    for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
    {
        char frameName[128] = {0};
        sprintf(frameName, "AngleSelector%d.png", i);
        animate->addSpriteFrameWithFileName(frameName) ;
    }

    animate->setDelayPerUnit(0.35f); // This animation contains 3 frames, will continuous 2.8 seconds.
    animate->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true); // Return to the 1st frame after the 3rd frame is played.

    CCAnimate *animaction = CCAnimate::create(animate);
    CCRepeatForever *rt = CCRepeatForever::create(animaction);
    Player->runAction(rt);

    this->setTouchEnabled(true);


void HelloWorld::ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    Player->stopAllActions();

}
```

Comment: that would be in the sprite's spriteFrame or displayFrame property, depending on version

Comment: Cocos2dx 2.2.2 am using. there any prioperty is there ?

Comment: check the class reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved using following code. image index will return your current display frame

```
CCTexture2D* tex = Player->getTexture();
int imageIndex = 0;
for (int i=0; i< animate->getFrames()->count(); i++) {
    CCAnimationFrame *frame = (CCAnimationFrame*)animate->getFrames()->objectAtIndex(i);
    CCTexture2D *tex2 = frame->getSpriteFrame()->getTexture();
    if (tex->isEqual(tex2)) {
        imageIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```